# Trouble with AJAX, JS, and Select2

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-select2

I apologize if I am doing something stupid, but I am brand new to Select2 and Ajax and am having a hell of a time trying to get this work.  I am attempting to create my own json file (<s>link removed</s>) to use with a form (<s>link removed</s>) I am building.  Using Firefox Lite in Chrome, I am able to get a response from my server (200 OK), but the select box does not display the search results. My json file appears to validate correctly using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com.  You can also see it at

Any thoughts or tips?

**json.php source:**

```
<?
    $myArray = array(
            array( "id" => "id1", "text" => "title1" ),
            array( "id" => "id2", "text" => "title2" )
            );

    echo json_encode($myArray); 

?>
```

**select.php source:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="select2/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function movieFormatResult(movie) {
            var markup = "<table class='movie-result'><tr>";
            markup += "<td class='movie-info'><div class='movie-title'>" + movie.title + "</div>";
            markup += "</td></tr></table>"
            return markup;
        }

        function movieFormatSelection(movie) {
            return movie.title;
        }

    </script>
    <script id="script_e6">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#e6").select2({
                placeholder: "Search for a movie",
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
                    url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            q: term, // search term
                            page_limit: 10,
                            apikey: "my-api-key" // please do not use so this example keeps working
                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
                        return {results: data.movies};
                    }
                },
                formatResult: movieFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                formatSelection: movieFormatSelection,  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop" // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script id="script_e6a">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#e6a").select2({
                placeholder: "Search for a movie",
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
                    url: "http://willwelch.net/play/nhs/pstudents/json.php",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: function () {
                        return;
                    },
                    results: function () { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                        return {results: data};
                    }
                },
                formatResult: movieFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                formatSelection: movieFormatSelection,  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop" // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
            });
        });
    </script>    
</head>

<body style="height:500px;">
    <p>original example (works)</p>
    <input type="hidden" class="bigdrop" id="e6" style="width: 600px; display: none;"><br><br>
    <p>my version (does not work)</p>
    <input type="hidden" class="bigdrop" id="e6a" style="width: 600px; display: none;">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your url (willwelch.net) as a jsonp call. In your php, you must capture the param `callback` passed by the ajax call, and wrap the result in a function call, with the function name = the contents of the callback parameter.

So the call to your php might be:

```
 http://willwelch.net/play/nhs/pstudents/json.php?callback=myfunc
```

And what you should return is:

```
 myfunc([{"id":"id1","text":"title1"},{"id":"id2","text":"title2"}])
```

Note the ajax call will add the callback param automatically.

**Edit**

Also you need to change your `return` method to add `data` as an input parameter:

```
         results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
               return {results: data};
         }
```

Comment: I actually meant to use json (not jsonp).  When I update my code to reflect this and also your second fix, the select is now populated, but all items say 'undefined'.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are you sure you are not getting CORS errors in the JavaScript console (something like *..not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*). Any one connecting to willwelch.net who is not from that domain **will** get that error. 2. Can you try it without the `formatResult` and `formatSelection` lines? These functions appear specific to the rottentomatoes API.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I was calling movie.title when I should have been calling movie.text.